# Why is my like function not working for my django code?

Tags: python, django, cs50

I'm currently doing the CS50 week 4 network problem and I keep having issue with my 'like' and 'unlike' button. It refuses to change even though I click and refresh it multiple times. I've been at it for days and cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

Here is my code.

**Like handler function:**

```
function likeHandler(id, whoYouLiked){
if(whoYouLiked.index0f(id) >= 0){
    var liked = true;
} else {
    var liked = false;
      }

if(liked === true){
          fetch(`/remove_like/${id}`)
          .then(response => response.json)
          .then(result => {
          console.log(result)
        })
} else{`your text`
          fetch(`/add_like/${id}`)
          .then(response => response.json)
          .then( result => {
          console.log(result)
        })
      }
}
```

**Btn for liking in index:**

```
{% if post.id in whoYouLiked %}
        <button class = "btn btn-info fa fa-thumbs-down col-1" onclick="likeHandler({{ post.id }}), {{ whoYouLiked }}" id="{{ post.id }}" ></button>
{% else %}
        button class = "btn btn-info fa fa-thumbs-up col-1" onclick="likeHandler({{ post.id }}), {{ whoYouLiked }}" id="{{ post.id }}" ></button>
{% endif %}
```

**Like function in my views as well as my URL:**

```
def remove_like(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like = Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
    like.delete()
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Like removed!"})


def add_like(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    newLike = Like(user=user, post=post)
    newLike.save()  
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Like added!"})
```

*Please do let me know if you need to see anymore of my code!*

Comment: sorry while editing i removed the < from my button code but its there in my code lol